# What is ExistentialMetatype in Swift

Tags: swift

This wonders me a little bit. In Swift try the following:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        println(self.superclass) //Outputs "(ExistentialMetatype)"
    }
```

This gives the output on console to be **ExistentialMetatype**

Going deep into the Swift's *NSObject* framework it declares this `superclass` as a read-only computed property of type `AnyClass`

```
    var superclass: AnyClass! { get }
```

But nowhere is there a mention of this word `ExistentialMetatype`. I don't know why but it reminds of Objective-C's runtime (probably its the word Metatype in it). Does anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, *types* (instances of *metatypes*) get printed as unhelpful things like `(Metatype)` or `(ExistentialMetatype)`. `AnyClass` is `AnyObject.Type`, a metatype. So if you try to print an `AnyClass` you will get this unhelpful description.

However, classes in Objective-C are objects with nice descriptions. Swift allows casting of class types into objects so they can be used in the Objective-C way. If you cast it into `AnyObject` first, you will see the name of the class:

```
println(self.superclass as AnyObject!)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, what is going on is that AnyClass is a specially crafted protocol type - the protocol type that every "reference type" (class) automagically conforms to

Protocol types are sometimes called "existential types" by your friendly compiler engineers (for instance http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type)

In this case, you're looking at the type object that represents such an existential type, the "metatype" as you say. Hence 'ExistentialMetatype'!

Comment: Actually, `AnyObject` is the protocol that every reference type conforms to. `AnyClass` is an alias for `AnyObject.Type`, i.e. a protocol that every metatype for reference types conforms to.