# Objective-C Runtime API in swift

Tags: swift

I try to use the old Objective-C runtime APIs in swift. But I can't get the correct result:

```
import Foundation

class MyClass
{
    let a : UInt32 = 10
    func test(){ }
}

var obj = MyClass()

println("%@",class_getSuperclass(MyClass)) //ExistentialMetatype
println("%@",objc_getClass(UnsafePointer<Int8>(unsafeAddressOf(obj)))) //nil
```

The result of first `println` is "`ExistentialMetatype`". The second `println` gives `nil`. My Questions are:

- What is the type of "ExistentialMetatype"?
- I also tried other runtime APIs but they all failed. So far, I can't find any Apple docs related to this topic. And It seems like the only way to get the meta-class(isa pointer) information is through [reverse engineering](http://www.eswick.com/2014/06/inside-swift/).
- Does this mean Swift prevents us from accessing the meta-class at runtime?

The above code is running on XCode 6.1.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342832/what-is-existentialmetatype-in-swift

Comment: Thanks, I've already read that post. It seems like `AnyClass` can not be simply casted as `AnyObject`.Here is the definition of `AnyClass`:`typealias AnyClass = AnyObject.Type`